# Detection of iphone turn modem mode on/off

Tags: iphone, ios

I need the way of detection is iPhone currently have modem mode (wifi spot) on.
When it's on at the top of the screen system draw big blue area, that move the content are down.

Sure I can constantly check the content area size to detect it's changes - but it is not good solution. Is there any events what can come to my app so I can do some things in this moment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, do you need to detect if personal hotspot is on or simply trying to adjust your interface to an enlarged status bar?

To detect personal hotspot, there's a solution here by detecting the network interface
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16856241/2763891

As far as I know, the status bar doubles it's regular size when:

- a phone call is going on
- personal hotspot is on
- an app is using the microphone at the background
- ...

Usually, [view autosizing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html) fits the new size of your view automatically. If you're positioning your views manually, [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) provides notification on changes of the frame of the status bar.

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)oldStatusBarFrame
```

Comment: great, didChangeStatusBarFrame - will suit my needs. It's simply don't come into my mind when I searched for this. Thank you.